# Create a Loop to import Data via Multiple URLs

Tags: python

I am trying to create a loop to download data from a website between 2014 and 2017. I've created a simple loop that should download data from this link, but for 2015, 2016, and 2017. The only text that needs to change in the link is the year:

https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/view_text_file.php?filename=42887h**2014**.txt.gz&dir=data/historical/stdmet/

**Revised:**

```
import urllib

core = 'https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/view_text_file.php?filename=42887h'
year = 2014
end = '.txt.gz&dir=data/historical/stdmet/'

for i in range(0,3):

        year += 1
        year_fixed = str(year)
        urllib.urlretrieve(core+year_fixed+end)
```

There error that I receive is at the first website address:

```
AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'
```

[image]

For some reason it is not importing any data from 2014 - 2017. Is there a better way about creating this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the question (problem you try to solve)?

Comment: Don't reset `year = 2014` in the loop.

Comment: Also, in `core = “...` That is not a regular double quote. Should be `core = "...`.

Comment: your quote is not what you think it is, the last one " you copy pasted that and it is not ascii

Comment: First of all, don't keep changing question after receiving previous answer that worked. Secondly, "AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'" sounds as if you are using Python 3, which has the urllib split in submodules, so you should probably use urllib.request.urlretrieve() instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With python3 (3.7 used here) and the requests module it could be simplified to this:

```
import requests
for year in range(2014, 2018):
    url = f'https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/view_text_file.php?filename=42887h{year}.txt.gz&dir=data/historical/stdmet/'
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(r.text)
```

instead of printing, you could save the output to a file

// edit for Python < 3.6, use str.format()

```
url = "https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/view_text_file.php?filename=42887h{}.txt.gz&dir=data/historical/stdmet/".format(year)
```

Further reading about string formatting: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: This is much better way.

Comment: The requests package seems more efficient according to its vignette, however I the snippet doesnt work. SyntaxError: invalid syntax on line 2

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3?

Comment: I am using Python3

Comment: Which version of python3? (python --version). The formatted string literals f"" are available from python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

The following works well in Python 3. The loop creates individual files after retrieving the data.

```
import urllib.request

core = 'https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/view_text_file.php?filename=42887h'
year = 2014
end = '.txt.gz&dir=data/historical/stdmet/'

for i in range(0,3):

        year += 1
        year_fixed = str(year)
        filename = "text" + str(i) + ".txt"
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(core+year_fixed+end, filename)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it produces "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal"

Comment: I get the same error in the post. This snippet also pulls in the what you see in the screenshot.

Comment: You're probably using a different version of python.

Comment: If you're using Python 3 then try replacing `urllib.request.urlretrieve()` in place of `urllib.urlretrieve()`

Comment: Correct, however the environment only has `core`, `i `, `year`, and `year_fixed`. Rather than 4 dataframes. The `urllib.request.urlretrieve()` puts them in a tmp folder on my HDD.

Comment: You should save the file. Something like `urllib.request.urlretrieve(core+year_fixed+end, "text.txt")` does for single file. To have it in a loop and create multiple files use `exec`